# Referências das Subs e Funções onde está sendo usada sumiu no meu Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: SS]

Onde seto a opção no Visual Studio 2015 de mostrar a referência de Sub/Função, onde elas estão sendo usada.

(Ex: Função GravarDados > Chamo ela no Botão Salvar), ai em cima da Função aparece a referência e mostra onde ela foi chamada. Aqui no meu VS sumiu.

Comment: Uso o Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: Então não sumiu, nunca esteve aí.

Comment: Cara eu fiz a pergunta justamente porque sumiu, estou chamando essa Sub e essa Função e não aparece a referência como disse acima.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Este recurso é chamado de CodeLens. Ele pode ser habilitado ou desabilitado nas configurações do Visual Studio (Tools -> Options).

[image: CodeLens Options]

[image: CodeLens no editor]

Note que este recurso só está disponível no [Visual Studio Enterprise ou Professional](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx). Esta é uma das poucas coisas que a Community não tem em relação ao Professional.

Pode ser que tinha alguma extensão que fazia isto e ela pode ter sido desabilitada por alguma razão.

Ainda assim é possível achar onde foi usado com <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

O [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) pode ajudar ainda mais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Era exatamente isso o meu muito obrigado! =)